# C++: Enforce Singleton on Subclasses of ABC

Tags: c++, singleton, abstract-base-class

Whithin an already exisitng Simulation framework I am trying to implement the state pattern on already exising abstract base classes of models. As the model class is only an ABC, so should be the states.
I am searching for a way to enforce the singleton pattern on all possible child classes of the states' ABC.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
template<typename T> class SingletonBase
{
public:
[...]
static T* getInstance()
{
    if (instance == nullptr)
    {
        instance = new T();
    }
    return instance;
}
protected:
  SingletonBase(){}
  static T* instance;
```

Here is the ABC of my state:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename StateType>
class State : public SingletonBase<StateType>
{
public:
  virtual ~State(){}

  virtual void foo(Context<A,B,StateType>* ctx, ...) = 0;

  virtual void bar(Context<A,B,StateType>* ctc, ...) = 0;

protected:
  State(){}

virtual void changeState(Context<A, B, StateType>* ctx, State<A, B, StateType>* state);

private:
  friend class SingletonBase<State<A, B, StateType>>;
};
```

The context class takes the same three template parameters as it needs to know the type of its state.
And a new class templates finally inherits from Context and the ABC of the used models.

I now tried to create a base class for concrete states use in a simulation the folowing way (this base class is needed so that all Context have the same type):

```
class StateBaseForSimulationScenario : public State<foobar, barfoo, StateBaseForSimulationScenario>
```

Now I encouter two problems:

1) Obviously the getInstance() method of every child of the state base will only produce a statebase

2) If I instead of using the statebase type as template parameter use the concrete type, the Context won't match (e.g. Context with parameter StateIdle is obviously not the same type as Context with parameter StateProducing)

So my question is: Is there a way to enforce all future child classes of State to be a Singleton? Or is it just not possible this way in C++?

P.S.: If your answer is that Sigletons are an anti pattern/bad design etc. or that I just should use boost: Please don't. Thanks.